# Unit test with enzyme, mocha, sinon and reactjs. How to see what the spy is called with?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, enzyme

I have tried to work out why this test is failing but cannot determine the reason, because I cannot see what the sinon spy object is being called with.

Is there a better way to test sinon.calledWith so it will show the result and expected result?

In the test below the following check passes `expect(onLoginClick.called).to.equal(true);` but this does not `expect(onLoginClick.calledWith(expected)).to.equal(true);`.

1. Any ideas why?
2. How can I check myself by seeing the actual value onLoginClick is called with vs the expected?

I am running the tests via "npm run test", the project can be cloned and run from https://github.com/Rob-Leggett/react_redux_webpack

Thanks for any answers and time taken to assist with this question.

**Test**

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

import Login from '../app/components/login/Login';

describe('<Login/>', function () {

  it('should click login button with credentials', () => {
      // given
      const expected = { username: 'test', password: 'user' };

      const errors = [];
      const onLoginClick = sinon.spy();

      const wrapper = mount(<Login errors={errors} onLoginClick={onLoginClick} />);

      // when
      wrapper.ref('username').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'test'}});
      wrapper.ref('password').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'user'}});

      wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

      // then
      //expect(onLoginClick.calledWith(expected)).to.equal(true);
      expect(onLoginClick.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

**Component**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class Login extends Component {

  renderErrors() {
    const { errors } = this.props;

    return errors.map((error, i) => {
      return (
          <p key={i} style={{color:'red'}}>{error}</p>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type='text' ref='username' className="form-control" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} placeholder='Username'/>
          <input type='password' ref='password' className="form-control" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} placeholder='Password'/>
          <button onClick={() => this.handleLogin()} className="btn btn-primary">
            Login
          </button>

          {this.renderErrors()}
        </div>
    )
  }

  handleLogin() {
    const { onLoginClick } = this.props;

    const credentials = {
      username: this.refs.username.value.trim(),
      password: this.refs.password.value.trim()
    };

    onLoginClick(credentials)
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react_redux_webpack_client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A ReactJS Client",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test/helpers/browser.js test/**/*.spec.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --hot --inline",
    "build": "webpack -p --display-error-details"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Rob-Leggett/react_redux_webpack.git"
  },
  "author": "Robert Leggett",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Rob-Leggett/react_redux_webpack",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Rob-Leggett/react_redux_webpack/issues"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.9.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out more then true/false in your test, you can can get the args from the Sinon spy like this:

```
const spyCall = onLoginClick.getCall(0);
expect(spyCall.args[0]).to.equal(expected)
```

Now the failing test should show you the args you really got.
See http://sinonjs.org/docs/